# UIWebView content with scrollable iframe

Tags: iphone, iframe, uiwebview, webkit

I have a html page with iframes where part of the page is scrollable while other parts are not.

Is there a way to display this in a UIWebView and allow scrolling these iframe sections?
So far I see that only the entire page is scrolling.

Comment: can you share your URL ?

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible.
The UIWebView is composed by a UIScrollView, the content is rendered inside it.

So, basically what you want is to create an UIScrollView inside an UIScrollView. Dispatching the gestures will be a big challenge. Which one should scroll?